# How to easily use Windows 7 search advanced options?

Tags: windows-7, search, windows-search

Is there an alternative to trying to remember all the advanced search options? Like an actual GUI as we had for windows XP?

As powerful as Windows Search apparently is, I cannot possibly remember [all the options available](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/products/winfamily/desktopsearch/technicalresources/advquery.mspx). How is a mere mortal like my Dad supposed to understand and retain all this?

I get the shakes every time i need to find something on Win 7. Anyone have some relief?

Part 2: Why does it RE-run a search if i add a column and try to sort on that?

Comment: "all the options available" Link broken, please fix if you can. Maybe this one will do?..http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965711%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Well, for a start you get plenty of help in composing the search queries. I don't know about you but the frequency with which I compose ridiculously complicated search queries are ... rare.

In any case, have you noticed that there is a little line of readily-insertable constraints showing up just below where you type in your search?

[image: Search box in Windows 7's Explorer]

Clicking on one of those "Add a search filter" links will give a little more UI, tailored to the type of filter—but you can also just type away:

[image: Adding a date filter]    [image: Adding a size filter]

Comment: Perhaps he is typing his search in the Start menu (which is what I usually do)... the helpful features don't show up there.

Comment: @cone: Well, then using Win+F instead of just Win should solve that. You can still type instantaneously there. However, the OP's second complaint with columns and so suggests that it isn't in the start menu.